# Libgdx/Java 2D Duengon collision and collision from all sides

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection, collision

im currently developing a small game, a duengon rpg crawler.It all works fine and today i tried to implement a collision mechanic, because you shouldnt go trough walls... The map is completly randomly generated.
I havent found any good tutorials how to setup a collision mechanic for libgdx or java, just something like this :

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.overlaps(r2);
```

That worked yes, but it didnt showed me, where the Rectangle colides with the other one. All i wanna have, is a good tutorial about java or libgdx, how to make a all 4 sides collision, step by step :) Or an example...

Thanks for your attention and your help.

Comment: You can use box2d, while generating your map add fixtures and it will handle all collision/physics for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) Already tried that, but im trying to port my game onto Android ... and my game got about 600 physic objects sooo its way to bad for using on mobile :/

Comment: maybe you're doing the wrong way, i got a tiled game 300x300 with a lot of physic objects (arround 1k+) and it runs fine on android. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88319703/connections.jpg

Comment: Hmmm... than i gonna try it again :) thanks man ! But you dont know how to make a physic collision, based on rectangles ? ^^ By the way, are you a german ? Your project name is "Project Dorf" :)

Comment: Well if you don't want to use a physics engine you must implement everything by hand, like collision between polygon and rectangle, circle and polygon, triangles and so on, it will be a hell of a work, everything you should use math so i recomment you to take a look at the intersector class that should make you take less effort.. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html